# Is there a way to refactor a switch statement that is unique to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, switch-statement, refactoring

I'm a new hire on a C# (.NET 4.0) project but I come from a C/C++ background.  I have been instructed to "generally improve our product" and came across a method that is an even 1000 lines long that is mostly comprised of a single switch statement with 15 cases, each around 60 lines of code.

Before this gig I would have kept the same general format but extracted 15 functions and then worked out how to share/point to local variables/class data members as needed.  However, I now have access to a wide array of mysterious new tools and I can't shake the feeling that there is a "C# smart" way to go about this.

Is there a way to refactor this switch statement in C#(4.0) that could not be done in C++?

**EDIT:** Here is a sanitized and summarized form of the code:

```
private void DeviceRequest(List<OpRequest> currentOp, double adjTime) {
     //local variables

    while (/*condition*/)
    {
        //Some setup
        //Some initialization

        try
        {
            switch (OperationType)
            {
                case Setup:
                    //Message header setup through 'if-else' statements
                    //Message sending
                    //Many nested 'if' checks, a few less 'else's
                    break;

                case Initiate:
                    //Message header setup through 'if-else' statements
                    //Message sending
                    //Many nested 'if' checks, a few less 'else's
                    break;

                case Acquire:
                    //Message header setup through 'if-else' statements
                    //Message sending
                    //Many nested 'if' checks, a few less 'else's
                    break;

                case Measure:
                    //Message header setup through 'if-else' statements
                    //Message sending
                    //Many nested 'if' checks, a few less 'else's
                    break;

                case Reset:
                    //Message header setup through 'if-else' statements
                    //Message sending
                    //Many nested 'if' checks, a few less 'else's
                    break;

                //12 more cases, all fairly similar.
            }
        }

        catch (RunTimeError err)
        {
            //A few lines of code
        }

        finally
        {
          //Objective measure of time passage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell us a bit more about the switch cases. What is your general take on the duplication between cases?

Comment: Each time you see a `switch` statement you know there's a missed opportunity to subclass. Unfortunately, the question is too broad to suggest a specific refactoring.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not looking for a specific refactoring, I'm curious if there are any features/keywords special to C# that are used in refactoring a situation as I have described.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as any other OO-language. Pull out methods or refactor into inheritance or a dispatch table. There isn't a need to look for the opportunity to use a language feature- those opportunities will present themselves (e.g.) the next time you want to use a function pointer. C# doesn't fundamentally change OO design, it just makes certain scenarios much simpler. (+1 b/c this question is nowhere near bad enough to warrant a negative score.)

Comment: The edit with added code makes this question specific enough to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch` on an `enum` can often be replaced by a `Dictionary` of actions. In order to prepare for this, each action must process the same inputs.

If you could refactor the code into a collection of 15 methods with identical signatures, you could put them into a `Dictionary<OpRequest,DelegateType>` where `DelegateType` is a delegate with the signature of your method.

For example, if each of the 15 methods has the signature below

```
private void SetupAction(double adjTime) {
    ...
}
void InitiateAction(double adjTime) {
    ...
}
```

you could build a dictionary of actions

```
private readonly IDictionary<OpRequest,Action<double>> OpActions = new Dictionary<OpRequest,Action<double>> {
    {OperationType.Setup, SetupAction}
,   {OperationType.Initiate, InitiateAction}
,   ... // and so on
};
```

With this dictionary in place you could rewrite your loop as follows:

```
while (/*condition*/) {
    //Some setup
    //Some initialization
    try {
        Action<double> action;
        if (OpActions.TryGetValue(opType, out action)) {
            action(adjTime);
        } else {
            ... // Report an error: unknown OpRequest
        }
    } catch (RunTimeError err) {
        ... //A few lines of code
    }
    finally {
        ... //Objective measure of time passage
    }
}
```